# Performing better adjustment - Nonlinear regression with python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have some information, which varies according to the day (x-axis), I would like to adjust it in a better way. I have used scipy.optimize.curve_fit and it fits well with the following function but I would like to adjust it in some better way.

A polynomial form would not be useful or imprecise for me, since the Y-axis values are cumulative, so it is unlikely that the curve will drop.

Could someone give me a hand on what I could add to the function to make it fit better?

Here is the data I use, as well as the formula with the parameter values.

```
>>> X
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
       18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34,
       35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51,
       52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66])
>>> y
array([  1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   1,   2,   2,   4,  15,  17,  38,  46,
        53,  61,  75, 100, 111, 133, 142, 152, 159, 170, 174, 179, 182,
       188, 190, 192, 196, 198, 199, 202, 205, 207, 214, 215, 216, 218,
       224, 229, 231, 233, 236, 236, 236, 237, 237, 237, 237, 237, 237,
       237, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 238, 239,
       243]) 

>>> def func(x,a,b):
    return a*np.exp(b/x)

>>> popt,pcov=curve_fit(func,X,y)
>>> a=popt[0]
>>> b=popt[1]
>>> yvals=func(X,a,b)
>>> plot1=plt.plot(X,y,'*',label='original values')
>>> plot2=plt.plot(X,yvals,'r',label='curve_fit values')
>>> plt.show()
>>> popt
array([357.97373884, -20.60549425])
```

[Curve Fit Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSsJf.png)

Thanks!

Comment: What is your goal? To find a model that accurately predicts future values? To find a simple equation that describes your data? To find an underlying mathematical relationship you suspect exist? What is the source of your data? Etc...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since your question is more related to nonlinear regression methods than programming, [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) would be a better site for it.

Comment: My goal is to be able to predict future values. On the X-axis are the days elapsed and on the Y-axis the accumulated cases of an disease.
I think that the behavior of contagion could be intertwined with some mathematical relationship. Thanks @orlp